# Rails Migrations Basic Workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a migration that creates a table 'pages' , this is my migration:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string "name" , :limit => 50
      t.integer "permalink"
      t.integer "position"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :pages
  end
end
```

and that I've created the appropriate migration file X_create_pages.rb and ran it(the table is created in the database).

Now after a few days I realize the structure isn't complete and I need to add another column to my pages table .

What is the best practice , do I create a new migration file with add_column method or do I just change the current migration file's up method -e.g just add my columns to the up method (and then move down a version and then up again - so to run the up method?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practice should be you create a new migration to add the new column.  This becomes the simplest and risk free path.  Of course, we can talk about unseen circumstances!

Updating original migration files should not be used after application is released to production; at least this is what the practice should be.  But, this also depends on applications, if you don't have a table that is referenced elsewhere then backing up the data, adding the column and restoring the data is also a possibility which is enabled by this approach of directly modifying the original migration file and rolling down that version and migrating up that version again.

While you are on development, the choice I guess is yours.  You could choose either!

Comment: But on a 'real' project with a team you would write a migration such as addSomeColumnToPages that all it does is add that column , and keep doing it for every new columns ?

Comment: Well vee is right depends of the project, you must be careful about adding columns because it changes depending of your actions in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Once a migration has been checked into source control it shouldn't be changed.

Modifying a migration on your development environment providing it hasn't been checked into source control is perfectly fine.

Once a migration has been checked in it may have been run by your team mates on their development environment or even been deployed and run in production.

Changing previously committed migrations is going to make you very unpopular in your team very quickly as team mates struggle to understand why their database schema is different from yours but all the migrations have been run.